# Angular-Testing with jest: TypeError: ... is not a function

Tags: angular, testing, error-handling, mocking, ts-jest

I have 2 services in Angular:

1. TestService imports the HelperService and uses the methods from it.

```
import { HelperService } from "./helper.service";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {


    constructor(private helperService: HelperService) {}


    add(a: number, b: number) : number{
        return this.helperService.add(a, b)
    }

    subtract(a: number, b: number) : number {
        return this.helperService.subtract(a, b)
    }

}
```

2. HelperService

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelperService {


    add(a: number, b: number) : number{
        return a + b
    }

    subtract(a:number, b:number) : number {
        return a - b
    }

}
```

My test for the testService looks like this:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HelperService } from './helper.service';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

describe('Test Service', () => {

    let testService : TestService;
    let addSpy: any;
    let subSpy: any;


    beforeEach(() => {

        addSpy = jest.spyOn(HelperService.prototype, 'add').mockReturnValue(50);
        subSpy = jest.spyOn(HelperService.prototype, 'subtract');

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                TestService,
                {provide: HelperService, useValue: addSpy},
                {provide: HelperService, useValue: subSpy}
            ],
        });

        testService = TestBed.inject(TestService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(testService).toBeTruthy();
    })

    it('should add two numbers', ()=> {
      const result = testService.add(25,25);
      expect(result).toBe(50);
    })


});
```

I get an Error for it('should add two numbers):
*TypeError: this.helperService.add is not a function*

can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance.

I have no idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

`jest.spyOn` returns a spy and not HelperService, so you're replacing your service by a wrong object in your provider.

If you just need a mock, you could try:

```
describe('Test Service', () => {
    let testService : TestService;
    let mockHelperService = {
        add: (a: number, b: number) => 50,
        subtract: (a: number, b: number) => 25
    };


    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {provide: HelperService, useValue: mockHelperService }
            ]
        });

        testService = TestBed.inject(TestService);
    });
...
```

If you need a spy to verify your calls, you could inject real HelperService and spy methods:

```
describe('Test Service', () => {
    let testService : TestService;
    let helperService: HelperService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
        testService = TestBed.inject(TestService);
        helperService = TestBed.inject(HelperService);

        jest.spyOn(HelperService.prototype, 'add').mockReturnValue(50);
        jest.spyOn(HelperService.prototype, 'subtract').mockReturnValue(25);
    });
...
```